# CVIRTE.dll Missing error?

Tags: windows, dll, microsoft-metro

I want to install a software on my PC but when i clicked to install it I got

> CVIRTE.dll Missing error

I search for this error but unable to download this dll file. Please provide any link to download this file
Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is the CVI Runtime Engine. It is needed to run Applications that were made with LabWindows/CVI or MeasurementStudio by National Instruments ( http://www.ni.com/lwcvi/ ). Usually, programmers of such applications also generate a Windows Installer Package for the application, which also does the installation of the CVI Runtime Engine. So , once you installed a CVI application like that, you usually can run other CVI application just by copying them (as long as they do not need additional packages from Ni). So, either run an installer of another application made with CVI, or just install the RTE. 
Be aware that there are new versions of the RTE with every new version of CVI, and the library is getting larger and larger. So maybe you can go for an older version of the RTE, it could be more compact.
The 2015 version of the RTE can be downloaded here :
http://www.ni.com/download/labwindowscvi-run-time-engine-2015/5374/en/

Good luck !